# MySQL Workbench UPDATE query with SubQuery

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create an update query that uses a subquery to update both the customer address and billing address however I can't quite wrap my head around how to go about doing that. Here is my Script.

```
drop table if exists billing_information;
drop table if exists customer;
drop table if exists product;
drop table if exists zip_code;
drop table if exists orders;


create table customer
(
    Customer_ID     integer(10) primary key,
    First_Name      varchar(25) not null,
    Last_Name       varchar(25) not null,
    Street_Address  varchar(50),
    Zip             integer(11),
    Product_ID      integer(10)
);

create table zip_code
(
    Zip             integer(11) primary key,
    City            varchar(25) not null,
    State           varchar(25) not null
);

create table product
(
    Product_ID      integer(10) primary key,
    Serial_Number   varchar(10) not null,
    Product_Name    varchar(25),
    cost            varchar(25) 
);

create table billing_information
(
    Customer_ID     integer(10) primary key,
    Street_Address  varchar(50) not null,
    Zip             integer(11) not null

);

create table orders
(
order_id integer(10),
Customer_ID integer(10) not null,
Product_ID integer (10) not null
);

alter table customer
add foreign key (Zip) references zip_code(Zip),
add foreign key (Product_ID) references product(Product_ID);

alter table billing_information
add foreign key (Customer_ID) references customer(Customer_ID),
add foreign key (Zip) references zip_code(Zip);

alter table orders
add foreign key (Customer_ID)   references customer(Customer_ID),
add foreign key (Product_ID)    references product(Product_ID);

set foreign_key_checks=0;

insert into customer (Customer_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Street_Address, Zip, Product_ID)
values  (1,'Tristin','Damon','779 Homestead Drive Hendersonville', 28792, 1),
        (2,'Whitney','Davis','885 Route 10 Wyandotte',48192, 2),
        (3,'Dyson','Harvie','121 Creekside Drive Waynesboro',17268, 3),
        (4,'Ward','Horatio','902 5th Street South North Bergen',07047, 4),
        (5,'Jem','Stanford','534 Broadway Pawtucket',02860, 5);

insert into zip_code(Zip,City,State)
values  (28792, 'Hendersonville', 'NC'),
        (48192, 'Wyandotte', 'MI'),
        (17268, 'Waynesboro', 'PA'),
        (07047, 'North Bergen', 'NJ'),
        (02860, 'Pawtucket', 'RI');

insert into product (Product_ID,Serial_Number,Product_Name, cost)
values  (1, 'N9TT-9G0A', 'C&C Red Alert', 3.99),
        (2, 'QK6A-JI6S', 'C&C Yuris revenge', 9.99),
        (3, 'XNSS-HSJW', 'C&C Red Alert 3', 19.99),
        (4, 'NHLE-L6MI', 'C&C Tiberium Sun', 3.99),
        (5, '6ETI-UIL2', 'C&C 4', 29.99);
-- dont ever buy this game, it's terrible also EA is a terrible company

insert into billing_information (Customer_ID, Street_Address, Zip)
values  (1,'779 Homestead Drive Hendersonville', 28792),
        (2,'885 Route 10 Wyandotte',48192),
        (3,'121 Creekside Drive Waynesboro',17268),
        (4,'902 5th Street South North Bergen',07047),
        (5,'534 Broadway Pawtucket',02860);

insert into orders (order_id, customer_id, Product_ID)
values  (1, 1, 1),
        (2, 2, 2),
        (3, 3, 3),
        (4, 4, 4),
        (5, 5, 5);


set foreign_key_checks=1;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see your UPDATE query.

Comment: Im not sure how to go about creating an update query the utilises a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what business logic you want to do, I think you may need this, try it;)

```
update customer c
inner join billing_information b
on c.Customer_ID = b.Customer_ID
set c.Street_Address = 'XXXXXX', b.Street_Address = 'XXXXXX'
```